# In python, read binary file as floats at once

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, binary-data, unpack

A data file `binaryFile.bin` was written as so in MATLAB:

```
stream = fopen (dst_file.c_str(),"wb");
fwrite(data,sizeof(float),4*num,stream);
fclose(stream);
```

I would like to retrieve this in Python. What I have tried thus far is:

```
fileName = '~/binaryFile.bin'
with open(fileName, mode='rb') as file: 
fileContent = file.read()
```

This gives me fileContent, which is a python string. (For example, the first couple samples look something like this: `"94QB\\x9a\\x99\\xe9@)\\"`).

I simply want to read back the entire `fileContent` as the original array of floats. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: How many bytes are in the file (`len(fileContent)`)? Is that the *whole file* you gave us? 19 bytes does not really fit any known float format.

Comment: @MartijnPieters As I said in the question, *the first couple samples* is that string. `len(fileContent)` gives 1919632

Comment: use the `array` module.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, may you please give a usage example for this case? Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319727/matlab-to-python-conversion-binary-file-read

Comment: You want to use `numpy.fromfile`. It will read it into a numpy array, which you can work with very similarly to a MATLAB matrix. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938208/converting-matlab-code-to-python

Comment: @TheBlackCat This seems to have sorted out my current problem. Thanks! I will come back if it hasn't.